# apply a custom numba njit function to pandas rolling object

Tags: python, pandas, numba

With the `pandas` 1.0.0 release, `.apply` now has the [ability](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) to use `numba jit` functions.

Is there a way to take advantage of this `.apply` functionality when using `.rolling` ?

For example I have a `pandas.DataFrame`, and a `numba_mean` function I would like to apply to get a rolling mean of 3 periods.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : np.random.rand(10)})
@nb.jit 
def numba_mean(x): 
    return np.sum(x) / len(x) 

df.A.rolling(3).apply(numba_mean)
```

However I get the below error, which means it does not work with `nopython` mode.

> Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "numba_mean" failed type inference due to: non-precise type pyobject

The Error traceback when applying `numba_mean` with `njit` rather than `jit`

> This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
>   - argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

I was wondering if there is a way to use the *numbafied* functions with a `pandas` `rolling` object ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify the [engine keyword](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html?highlight=pandas%20core%20apply#pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply) to let Pandas know you want to use Numba:

```
df.A.rolling(3).apply(numba_mean, engine='numba', raw=True)
```

Pandas can `jit` the function for you, but I get faster results when I do it myself. Perhaps Numba is recompiling for every call to `.apply()` and the timings below include compilation time.

With such a simple function, and a small amount of data for each call (window=3), it's unlikely that you'll get any speedup over the built-in function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(nogil=True)
def numba_mean(x):
    return np.sum(x) / x.size

def numpy_mean(x): 
    return np.sum(x) / x.size

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : np.random.rand(10000)})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have a more intricate `njit` function and this works like a charm :)